# Java listeners - Mouse left-press not registering while typing

Tags: java, awt

I am writing an application engine but I've found a problem in the event registering system. It seems like when typing on the keyboard and pressing the mouse left button, the window doesn't register the mouse press. But when I press the right mouse button while typing on the keyboard it actually registers.

To somewhat summarize the code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BasicEventTest implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    JFrame frame;

    /*********************************************** INPUT HANDLING ***********/
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        System.out.println(k.getKeyCode());
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m) {
        System.out.println("MOUSEPRESS " + m.getButton());
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {}
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {}

    /**************************************************** CONSTRUCTOR *********/
    public BasicEventTest() {
        frame = new JFrame("BasicEventTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
        frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);

        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.addMouseListener(this);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicEventTest test = new BasicEventTest();
    }
}
```

SOLVED:
Apparently in Windows 10, there's a setting in PC Settings->PC and devices->Mouse and touchpad, which controls the delay for registering clicks or moving the mouse after typing.

Comment: Your both conditions are the same: press while typing. anyway, FYI, your code it's working to me.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by that exactly? It doesn't explain why mouse button 3 is registering but mouse button 1 is not.

Comment: I mean it is working for me. May be a S.O level configuration?? (click disabled while typing or something?)

Comment: Also works for me using JDK8 on Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you very much for that suggestion, problem solved! I never could have thought it had to do with an OS-setting. There's apparently a setting for disabling clicks with a delay after typing...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the comments:

> Since the code is working as expected, you should probably check
>   configurations at S.O level